# iOS Programmatically Creating a View

Tags: ios, uiview, sleep

I am trying to create a new UIView programmatically from one of my `.m` files and then return to my existing view after 5 seconds. It seems that my logic is off because this is not doing what I am wanting. My code is below.

```
UIView *mainView = self.view;

UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] init];
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.view = newView;

sleep(5);
self.view = mainView;
```

It seems that it is just going to sleep for 5 seconds and then not doing anything.

I want to do the following,

- Store starting view
- Create new view
- Show gray view
- Wait 5 seconds
- Show my original view

Where am I going wrong? I feel like it has to be my logic or I am missing a key part of these steps.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` DO NOT USE sleep(). Group all your logic after the `sleep` part into a method and use `performSelector`.

Comment: @danypata Should I use the command, `[self performSelector:@selector(returnToMainView) withObject:mainView afterDelay:5.0]; ` and then create a method `- (void)returnToView:(UIView *)mainView{`

Comment: Yep, that should work.

Comment: It switches to the new view, then crashes after 5 seconds with the error code, `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe460900`

Comment: Use `[self performSelector:@selector(returnToMainView:) withObject:mainView afterDelay:5.0];` See the `:` at the end of returnToMainView.

Comment: Sweet! @danypata You're the best. Got it to work. If you would like to post an answer I can upvote and accept but if not, thanks a lot.

Comment: I added the comments as an answer if you wanna upvote it, anyway glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all DO NOT USE `sleep()`. You should use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method. Something like this:

```
-(void)yourMethodWhereYouAreDoingTheInit {
    UIView *mainView = self.view;
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.view = newView;
   [self performSelector:@selector(returnToMainView:)
              withObject:mainView 
              afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void)returnToMainView:(UIView *)view {
    //do whatever after 5 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)showBanner {
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:newView];

[newView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];
}
```

**Very preliminary, but should work**

Comment: `no visible @interface for UIView declares the selector addSubView`

Comment: `addSubview`, not `addSubView`.

Comment: Sorry about that, i wrote it from windows PC and didn't check. I have assumed that the topic author can understand what i want to say.

Answer (score 0):

Using GCD yields far more readable code, but ultimately its a matter of preference.

```
// Create grayView as big as the view and add it as a subview
UIView *grayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
// Ensure that grayView always occludes self.view even if its bounds change
grayView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:grayView];
// After 5s remove grayView
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [grayView removeFromSuperview];
});
```